# Ten dimensional representation of $S_6$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

For every three-element subset $A\subset S$ and $B=S\setminus A$ consider the symbol $e_{(A|B)}$ for which we assume that $e_{(A|B)}=e_{(B|A)}$. Then the vector space $V$ spanned by all $e_{(A|B)}$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is a ten-dimensional representation of $S_6$. How can I compute the decomposition of $V$ into direct sum of irreducible representations?

One summand is obvious - it is one dimensional space spanned by $e=\sum\limits_{A\subset S,|A|=3}e_{(A|B)}$.

Comment: This is a straightforward exercise (are you familiar with characters?) and therefore should be asked at math.stackexchange instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that it is a doubly transitive permutation representation. Therefore it decomposes as the sum of the trivial representation and an irreducible 9-dimensional representation.

Edit: indeed, stabiliser of $e_{A|B}$ is isomorphic to $3^2:D_8$, and corresponds to the stabiliser of a point in the action of $S_6$ on the projective line over $\mathbb{F}_9$. See e.g. http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/alt/A6/ for more details.

And finally, there are two irreducible 9-dimensional representations of $S_6$. To see which one occurs here, check the character value of an order 4 element with cyclic structure $(1,2,3,4)$, i.e. an element that is not in $A_6<S_6$.